# When did Jesus the Nazarene as King of the Jews (Matthew 27:37) fulfill the requirement for Melakim (Kings) of Yisrael from Deuteronomy 17:18?

Tags: matthew, jesus, contradiction, law, deuteronomy

If Deuteronomy 17:18 was the Law required for all Melakim (Kings) of Yisrael stating: "When he is seated on his royal throne, he shall have a copy of this Torah written for him on a scroll by the levitical priests." (וְהָיָ֣ה כְשִׁבְתּ֔וֹ עַ֖ל כִּסֵּ֣א מַמְלַכְתּ֑וֹ וְכָ֨תַב ל֜וֹ אֶת־מִשְׁנֵ֨ה הַתּוֹרָ֤ה הַזֹּאת֙ עַל־סֵ֔פֶר מִלִּפְנֵ֖י הַכֹּהֲנִ֥ים הַלְוִיִּֽם)

And Matthew 27:37 documents Jesus the Nazarene was labeled "King of the Jews" stating: "And set up over his head his accusation written, THIS IS JESUS THE KING OF THE JEWS." (27:37  καὶ ἐπέθηκαν ἐπάνω τῆς κεφαλῆς αὐτοῦ τὴν αἰτίαν αὐτοῦ γεγραμμένην· Οὗτός ἐστιν Ἰησοῦς ὁ βασιλεῦς τῶν Ἰουδαίων)

And Jesus the Nazarene explains his personal goals as Meshiach in Matthew 5:17 stating "Think not that I am come to destroy the law, or the prophets: I am not come to destroy, but to fulfill." (5:17  Μὴ νομίσητε ὅτι ἦλθον καταλῦσαι τὸν νόμον ἢ τοὺς προφήτας· οὐκ ἦλθον καταλῦσαι ἀλλὰ πληρῶσαι)

Then [Question] : **When did Jesus the Nazarene as King of the Jews (Matthew 27:37) fulfill the requirement for Melakim (Kings) of Yisrael from Deuteronomy 17:18?**

Comment: The hermeneutical basis you've provided for this question is very vague - are you asking whether the Romans who wrote the accusation believed Dt 17:18 to have been fulfilled? You don't appear to be asking about the meaning of *any* of these texts in their own context - it feels more like a **theology** question at face value, rather than a question about exegesis. I've swapped in the *contradiction* tag as that would seem to be the most likely way to bring this on-topic.

Comment: I get the sense that this question will most likely continue to generate lots of comments; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128742/discussion-on-question-by--when-did-jesus-the-nazarene-as-king-of-the-jews).

Comment: This is more of a pastiche of disconnected thoughts than an attempt at exegesis. It also confuses commandments with requirements. There were many kings who didn't follow these commandments yet they were kings. It also confuses earthly kings with the Messiah. Can you please rewrite this in order to clarify what passage you are trying to understand and specify what part of that passage you find confusing?

Comment: @Robert - The question simplified is if Matthew 5:17 set a goal to fulfill the law & Matthew 27:37 labeled Jesus the Nazarene "King of the Jews", when did Jesus fulfill the mosaic law requirement of Melakim from Deuteronomy 17:18?

Comment: Pilate labelled the suffering Christ "King of the Jews". Of course, Jesus is King of All, but what he did in the flesh is a parable for the spirit, as the kingdom of God is in the spirit, wheras a king according to the flesh is what the jews wanted. This constant confusion of the flesh with the spirit is what the Bible warns us about - even in Samuel -  and it's what those jews who thought the messiah would be a king were constantly stumbling over. Why keep repeating the same mistake? But asking *if* the instructions of Samuel were *parables* for Christ's kingship, then that'd be more sensible

Comment: @Robert - please do not get drawn into extended comment discussions. A chat has been created already as a suitable space for this. I'll be cleaning up these extra comments shortly.

Comment: Jesus became king at His birth!

Answer (score 1):

> When he is seated on his royal throne, he shall have a copy of this Teaching written for him on a scroll by the levitical priests.
> (Deut. 17:18, JPS Torah)

**Jesus entered his kingdom and sat upon his throne when he was raised from the dead and entered into heaven.** Revelation mentions Jesus taking a scroll.  There is a wide variety of interpretation as to the time he takes/took the scroll. We have no scripture telling when Jesus received the Torah scroll, but it may well have been Aaron or Moses giving it to him as fulfilling the Law when he entered into heaven and sat at the right hand of the Father.

Jesus told Pilate his kingdom wasn't here (βασιλεία ἡ ἐμὴ⸃ οὐκ ἔστιν ἐντεῦθεν, John 18:36, NA28)

> ἐντεῦθεν adv.—1. of place ... ἡ βασιλεία ἡ ἐμὴ οὐκ ἔστιν ἐ. my kingdom is not from here=ἐκ. τ. κόσμου τούτου J 18:36.
> --
> Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 268). Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

> 33 So Pilate entered his headquarters again and called Jesus and said to him, “Are you the King of the Jews?” 34 Jesus answered, “Do you say this of your own accord, or did others say it to you about me?” 35 Pilate answered, “Am I a Jew? Your own nation and the chief priests have delivered you over to me. What have you done?” 36 Jesus answered, “**My kingdom is not of this world**. If my kingdom were of this world, my servants would have been fighting, that I might not be delivered over to the Jews. But my kingdom is not from the world.” 37 Then Pilate said to him, “So you are a king?” Jesus answered, “You say that I am a king. For this purpose I was born and for this purpose I have come into the world—to bear witness to the truth. Everyone who is of the truth listens to my voice.” 38 Pilate said to him, “What is truth?”
> (John 18:33–38,ESV)

> And he said to her, “What do you want?” She said to him, “Say that these two sons of mine are to sit, one at your right hand and one at your left, in your kingdom.” 22 Jesus answered, “You do not know what you are asking. Are you able to drink the cup that I am to drink?” They said to him, “We are able.” 23 He said to them, “You will drink my cup, but to sit at my right hand and at my left is not mine to grant, but it is for those for whom it has been prepared by my Father.”
> (Matt. 20:21–23, ESV)

The two crucified on either side (here and here, ἐντεῦθεν καὶ ἐντεῦθεν) are the ones on Jesus' right and left when he entered his kingdom.

> There they crucified him, and with him two others, one on either side, and Jesus between them. 19 Pilate also wrote an inscription and put it on the cross. It read, “Jesus of Nazareth, the King of the Jews.”
> (John 19:18–19, ESV)

References to Jesus sitting on his throne:

> I adjure you by the living God, tell us if you are the Christ, the Son of God.” 64 Jesus said to him, “You have said so. But I tell you, from now on you will see the Son of Man **seated at the right hand of Power** and coming on the clouds of heaven.”
> (Matt 26:63–64, ESV)

> Being therefore exalted at the right hand of God, and having received from the Father the promise of the Holy Spirit, he has poured out this that you yourselves are seeing and hearing
> (Acts 2:33, ESV)

> The God of our fathers raised Jesus, whom you killed by hanging him on a tree. 31 God exalted him at his right hand as Leader and Savior, to give repentance to Israel and forgiveness of sins. 32 And we are witnesses to these things, and so is the Holy Spirit, whom God has given to those who obey him.”
> (Acts 5:30–32, ESV)

> and what is the immeasurable greatness of his power toward us who believe, according to the working of his great might 20 that he worked in Christ when he raised him from the dead and **seated him at his right hand** in the heavenly places, 21 far above all rule and authority and power and dominion, and above every name that is named, not only in this age but also in the one to come. 22 And he put all things under his feet and gave him as head over all things to the church, 23 which is his body, the fullness of him who fills all in all.
> (Eph. 1:19–23, ESV)

> If then you have been raised with Christ, seek the things that are above, where Christ is, seated at the right hand of God.
> (Col 3:1, ESV)

> He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high
> (Heb. 1:3, ESV)

> looking to Jesus, the founder and perfecter of our faith, who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross, despising the shame, and is seated at the right hand of the throne of God.
> (Heb. 12:2)

Reference to Jesus taking the scroll.

> And one of the elders said to me, “Weep no more; behold, the Lion of the tribe of Judah, the Root of David, has conquered, so that he can open the scroll and its seven seals.”
> 6 And between the throne and the four living creatures and among the elders I saw a Lamb standing, as though it had been slain, with seven horns and with seven eyes, which are the seven spirits of God sent out into all the earth. 7 And he went and took the scroll from the right hand of him who was seated on the throne.
> (Rev. 5:5–7, ESV)

Comment: Would the scroll in Revelation 5:7 be the original Torah scroll?

Comment: @חִידָה probably not, but he probably did receive the Torah scroll in heaven where even Aaron could give it to him as fulfilling the Law.  See edit to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over the rules for kings in Deut 17 and see how they are prophecies of Christ:

Deut 17.15-20 (LEB). Commentary provided in-line

> indeed, you may set a king over you whom **Yahweh your God will choose**,

God is the one who ultimately chooses. E.g.

- Matt 3.17 *And behold, there was a voice from heaven saying, “This is my beloved Son, with whom I am well pleased.”*
- Matt 17.5 *“While he yet spake, behold, a bright cloud overshadowed them: and behold a voice out of the cloud, which said, This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased; **hear ye him.**”*

> **from the midst of your countrymen** you must set a king over you; you are not allowed to appoint over you a man, a foreigner, who is not your countryman.

Here, there is wordplay because "midst" (qerev) can mean both "the inward parts" or "heart" but it can also mean "among you", and this wordplay happens through the old and new testament. Thus, the Kingdom of God is *within* you and the kingdom of God is *among* you -- both are true. Emmanuel means both "God is *among* us" and God is *within* us.  The Kingdom of God has invaded the Kingdom of Man, but it resides in the heart. However because it is in the heart of men, it is among men -- among your neighbors.

Additionally, this is also fulfilled in the more pedestrian sense, that the messiah must come of the house of Israel, that is, of those who see God. It will not come from those who can't see God.

> Except, he may **not make numerous for himself horses,**

Horses are types for human strength. The messiah will never operate by human strength, but by the power of the Father working within him.

- John 5.19 *So Jesus answered and said to them, “Truly, truly I say to you, the Son can do nothing from himself except what he sees the Father doing. For whatever that one does, these things also the Son does likewise.*
- John 5.30 *I can of mine own self do nothing: as I hear, I judge: and my judgment is just; because I seek not mine own will, but the will of the Father which hath sent me.*

> and he may **not allow the people to to go to Egypt in order to increase horses**, for Yahweh has said to you that you may never return.

The Messiah will never encourage people to obtain victory by their own strength, either. Nor will he use the power of the world (horses from Egypt = strength coming from the world) to obtain his goals or allow his followers to do the same.

- Matt 4.8-10 *Again the devil took him to a very high mountain and showed him all the kingdoms of the world and their glory, and he said to him, “I will give to you all these things, if you will fall down and worship me.” Then Jesus said to him, “Go away, Satan, for it is written, ‘You shall worship the Lord your God and serve only him.’ ”*
- John 6.63. *The Spirit gives life; the flesh profits nothing. The words I have spoken to you are spirit and they are life.*

> And he must **not acquire many wives for himself**, so that his heart would turn aside;

The Messiah can have only one wife, the Bride, which is the Israel of God - those who see God. This is why anyone wanting to be the bride must die to self and be joined to that bride, as there are not multiple brides and one cannot see God and live.

- Gal 2.20 *I am crucified with Christ: nevertheless I live; yet not I, but Christ liveth in me: and the life which I now live in the flesh I live by the faith of the Son of God, who loved me, and gave himself for me.*

> and he must **not accumulate silver and gold for himself excessively**.

Silver is a type for *redemption*. Gold is a type for *glory* and *resurrection*. The messiah must not seek his own glory or his own redemption, and must lay down his life. The father will then freely *give* him the glory that the son did not seek for himself.

- John 8.50 *And I seek not mine own glory: there is one that seeketh and judgeth.*
- John 10.15b *I lay down my life for the sheep.*

> “And then when he is sitting on the throne of his kingdom, then he shall write for himself a copy of this law on a scroll before the Levitical priests.
>
> And **it shall be with him, and he shall read it all the days of his life**,

Jesus, as the torah made flesh, *was the word*. He was the incarnate Word, thus the word was not only always with him but it was an inseparable part of his being, his meditation, his speech, and his sustenance.

- John 1.1-4 In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. The same was in the beginning with God. All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.
- Matt 4.3-4: *And when the tempter came to Him, he said, “If Thou be the Son of God, command that these stones be made bread.” But He answered and said, “It is written: ‘Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of God.’”*
- John 14.10 *Don't you believe that I am in the Father, and that the Father is in me? The words I say to you are not just my own. Rather, it is the Father, living in me, who is doing his work.*

> so that he may learn to revere Yahweh your God by **diligently observing all the word of this law and these rules**,
> so **as not to exalt his heart** above his countrymen and not to turn aside from the commandment to the right or to the left,

Christ was humble and perfectly obedient (which is something hard for an earthly king).

- Phil 2.5-8 *Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus: Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God: But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men: And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross.*

> **so that he may reign long over his kingdom**, he and his children in the midst of Israel.”

- Rev 11.15
  *And the seventh angel sounded, and there were great voices in Heaven, saying, “The kingdoms of this world are become the kingdoms of our Lord and of His Christ, and He shall reign for ever and ever!”*

Answer (score 0):

Deuteronomy 17:18 applied to earthly kings of the Jews. In Jesus' first coming, he wasn't an earthly king,
John 6:

> 15
> Jesus, knowing that they intended to come and make him **king** by force, withdrew again to a mountain by himself.

Comment: Would the scroll in Revelation 5:7 be the original Torah scroll for Jesus to read aloud (verbally copies) as King? | Then the law still remains in Heaven but not on Earth?

Comment: Could be but I do not know, sorry :)